# Binary requires exacly matching version of linked library

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

I want to be able to run my binary with any version of a specific libary (I assume that pinning the major version of a dynamic library is the default use-case)

In my Makefile I link the library like this:

```
LINKER_RT_FLAGS += -L../gr-digitizers/build/lib
LINKER_RT_FLAGS += -lgnuradio-digitizers
```

Inside that lib folder, symlinks are used:

```
$ ls -rtl
... libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.1.0.so -> libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.1.0.so.0.0.0
... libgnuradio-digitizers.so -> libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.1.0.so.0.0.0
... libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.1.0.so.0 -> libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.1.0.so.0.0.0
... libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.1.0.so.0.0.0
```

When running the binary, it only works fine if I provide the concrete `libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.1.0.so.0.0.0` on the system where it runs. It will not run if I rename the shared library to `libgnuradio-digitizers.so`. I would expect the other way around. The error looks like this:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.1.0.so.0.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I would like to be able to place a symlink on the system (E.g. `libgnuradio-digitizers.so -> libgnuradio-digitizers-5.0.2.0.so.0.0.0` ), so that I dont need to re-link the binary in order to use new versions of the dynamic library.

How can I tweak my Makefile so that the binary searches for the generic version, not for the concrete one ? Maybe some flag somewhere deep in my makefile could produce this unwanted result ?

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the shared library to define the name that the dynamic linker will look up when it tries to load the library.  There's a value specified during creation of the shared library that gives this name.

If you want to use a different name, then you need to change that name in the shared library.  It's not clear from your question whether you're building this shared library yourself or obtaining it from somewhere else: it can be changed after the fact but if this is a system-installed library maybe you don't want to do that.  Also, the way to do that varies by system (for example, on MacOS it's very different because, well, Apple just has to be its own special snowflake).

It's possible that you could change the name of the shared library at link time, in the program, rather than in the shared library itself.  I'm not sure if that can be done or how (maybe some linker map file?).  In any event, you want to be searching for information on changing the `soname` of shared libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! I am building the shared library myself via cmake (which so far is a mystery for me) ... I will try if I can fix things there !